# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Direct Update fails when returning to the foreground

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight 6.1.0
iOS 7 on iPhone 5s

We have a hybrid application that relies on Worklight server to do the direct update.  The problem occurs when the user minimizes and then re-opens the app, the user is able to see the update dialog, however the update would then fail due to the wrong WL-instance id.

Here is the init options:

```
var wlInitOptions = {
  connectOnStartup: true,
  onConnectionFailure: function() {
    WL.Logger.error("Failed to connect: " + arguments);
}


WLJSX.bind(window, 'load', function() {
  WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
}
```

Here are the steps I did:

1) Open the IOS application, it will bring me to the first index page of the application, say Page1
2) Press a button, which brings me to another page, say page2 using GluJs

```
glu.viewport('MyApp.page2');
```

3) Minimize the application.

4) Modify the WebResource and then deploy the modified Iphone app to Worklight server.

5) Re-open the minimized application, the user gets a prompt to direct update.

6) The update would then fail, and there is a log in Worklight console of the following:

> [ERROR ] FWLSE0203E: Received bad instance Id from client. Server
>   instance Id:'3f9eveddc7br5mq3ll0nq89miu', client instance
>   Id:'ut5m5f01i3bkq5l78m54uq137o'. [project trunk]

Comment: Please edit the question and provide full and detailed reproduction steps.

Comment: Also try with a blank new app without any modifications other than setting connectOnStartup to "true" in initOptions.js

Comment: Thanks. Will take a closer look...

Comment: Does this happen in DEVELOPMENT environment or PRODUCTION environment?

Comment: Hello, yes, this happens in development environment.

Answer (score 0):

1. The existence of `GluJs` nor step 1 at all is relevant to the process of Direct Update, which happens in 2 cases: on application startup, on return to foreground. Any "page movements" in the app are irrelevant.
2. You did not mention if this happens in your development environment (Worklight Studio in Eclipse with the built-in Worklight Development Server), or a production environment (clustered, not clustered, load balancer or not, etc...).

I've performed the following without any errors in Worklight Studio 6.1.0:

1. Created a new project and application
2. Added the iPhone environment
3. In `initOptions.js`, changed `connectOnStartup` from `false` to `true`
4. Run As > Xcode project
   Tested the app in both iOS 7.0 Simulator and iOS 7.1 beta 4 device (iPhone 5s)
5. Launched the application
6. Moved the application to the background (clicking the Home button)
7. In Eclipse, altered the HTML file
8. `Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server`
9. Brought the app back to the foreground
10. Direct Update detected and processed, application re-inited and displayed the updated HTML file